# Why are my css classes not working in my React project?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

For this one part I am trying to change the color of the text based on the character index, but the styling just is not working.

```js
import "../stylesheets/TypingTest.css"

const TypingTest = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {props.words.split("").map(function (char, idx) {
          return (
            <span className={props.index === idx ? "right" : "wrong"}>
              {char}
            </span>
          );
        })}
        <div>{props.index}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TypingTest;
```

```css
.right{
    color: var(red);
}
.wrong{
    color: var(green);
}
```

Also to note, if I take the logic out of the  so it becomes `className='right'` it still does not work

Comment: `red` and `green` are not valid CSS variable names, they need to be prefixed with `--`. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*)

Comment: but it's not 100% clear what you're trying to do - if these aren't meant to be CSS variables but simply the standard colors `red` and `green`, don't use `var` and just do (eg) `color: red;`

Comment: There is a package call classnames, it is for dynamic css `npm i classnames`

Answer (score 2):

Because your css is wrong:

```
.right {
    color: var(red); <--- you are try to use a css variable.
}
.wrong {
    color: var(green); <--- you are try to use a css variable.
}
```

I you want to use css variables you can define:

```
--red: red;
--green: green:

.right {
    color: var(--red);
}
.wrong {
    color: var(--green);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should it not be

`var(--red)`

And

`var(--green)`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties